# C++/CLI use a string between several functions of a form

Tags: string, textbox, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a problem I spent a day looking on to solve.
I am a newbie in visual c++ and I use Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Forms Applications.

I want to take from a textBox the data inputted and use them in several event handlers. More specifically, I take the data with

```
button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ word = textBox1->Text;
}
```

My problem is when I go to the event handler of button2, I apparently don't have the `string word` with the data inputted from textBox1 since the `string word` is a local variable. How can I solve this?

Comment: Create an empty string before two button functions, then when you press button 1 assign it a value of `textBox1->Text`. And now you will be able to use it in button 2 function.

Comment: great,thank you very much,my only problem is i dont get to see the word variable when i add a break point in the debugging process.
Thanks again

Comment: No problem, however I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with this debugger problem. Hope you find the way.

Comment: Its cool.I somehow solve it.Thanks again for your help.Something that easy got me in such a trouble